# Android Master number

Tags: android, variables

this may be kind of a confusing question, but I'll try to make it as simple as possible.

Ok so I am making a game, and in the game, there is one master number, called money. What I want is that if that money is a specific value, I want them to be able to press a button, that will add a specific amount of money to the original money, and I want the new master number to be the sum of the two. I know a variable can not be initialized twice, so I was wondering how to go about this. I'm only a beginner, so any help/tips are appreciated.

```
if money < cost
enable button
else disable button
when pressed, money + cost
output master money
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple app to help get you started.  I set a specific value for the money master number.  You will need to replace that assignment with your logic.

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvMoney" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Claim Money"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Double money = 14.00;
    Double cost = 15.00;
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoney)).setText(format.format(money));

        button.setEnabled(false);
        if (money < cost) {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                money += cost;
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoney)).setText(format.format(money));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I just have one question, though. Say if there is one more button, and I want that button to do the same task as this, but that button uses the updated value of money. When I use the variable money the second time, it's going to use 14, and not the updated 29, right? I want it to use 29, and that was my main issue before as well.

Comment: See my changes above.  I added the line 'money += cost;' which will update the value of money.  I also removed the addition of 'cost' in the following line.  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.